# Cannot inspect variable inside Indy OnExecute event

Tags: debugging, delphi-xe7, indy10

using Indy with Delphi XE8 for a Tcp Server application I had necessity to inspect some local variables inside OnExecute event.

But setting a Breakpoint I do not understand why I get error "E2003 undeclared identifier"
trying to inspect or watch such local variables, as frame.

```
procedure TformMain.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  frame, answer: string;
begin
    ... 
    frame := ReadLn(cETX, 50, 1024); 
    ...
    Thread.Queue(nil, procedure
                  begin
                    mmLog.Lines.Add(AContext.Binding.IP +'Bad Frame: '+ frame);
                  end
    ...
end;
```

Instead, in the thread queue I use to send info to the GUI, I can inspect correctly the Binding.IP, dispite to local strings...

Any idea if I am using the Delphi debugger in the right/wrong way ?

Comment: Where is your break point? Inside `IdTCPServer1Execute` or inside the anon method?

Comment: Inside IdTCPServer1Execute, after  frame := ReadLn();  to inspect the frame local variable.

Comment: The thing about `frame` is that it is captured by the anon method. It is no longer lives in the stack frame for `IdTCPServer1Execute`. Now it is a data member of the [compiler generated class that implements the anon method interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955052/how-are-anonymous-methods-implemented-under-the-hood/39955392#39955392). I guess that just confuses the debugger. Delphi's debugger is a bit like that. Not much you can do beyond resorting to trace debugging.

Comment: Many thanks David, so I don't waste time trying to understand what happens.  At least I can rely in the old debug methods :-)