# Strange behaviour of TypeInfo by anonymous methods

Tags: delphi, anonymous-methods, delphi-10.2-tokyo, typeinfo

For a piece of code that needs the type "family" of a generic type, I try to use the `TypeInfo` to retrieve the required information.

```
class function GetTypeKind<T>:TTypeKind;
```

For most types I can figure this out. But the anonymous method type behaves unexpected.

I have an anonymous method type defined as:

```
TMethodProc = reference to procedure;
```

And I try to get the type information:

```
MyKind := GetTypeKind<TMethodProc>;

class function GetTypeKind<T>:TTypeKind;
var 
  TI: PTypeInfo;
begin
  TI := TypeInfo(T);

  ...
end;
```

I know there is some compiler magic behind the anonymous methods. But I get the following result:

```
TI.TypeData.IntfParent == IInterface
TI.TypeData.IntfFlags == [(out of bounds)6]
```

The flags have an unexpected value, `TIntfFlag` has three values so a 6 is unexpected. The GUID is also not a guid. It has a repeating set of the same 8 bytes, mostly 00. For example (0, 225, 48, 180, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 225, 48, 180, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Are anonymous methods excluded from `TypeInfo` or can it be useful with some tweaks.

Also, is the (strange) 6 an undocumented feature, or can it be any value?

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing really unusual about this.

An anonymous method is implemented as a compiler-generated interface that has an `Invoke()` method matching the same signature as the anonymous method.  That is why the `TTypeKind` is `tkInterface` and the `IntfParent` is `IInterface`.

Behind the interface is a compiler-generated implementation class that contains the captured variables, and the body of the anonymous method within its `Invoke()` implementation.

[How are anonymous methods implemented under the hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955052/)

The `IntfFlags` is a [`TIntfFlagsBase`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.TIntfFlagsBase), which is a [`Set`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets) of [`TIntfFlag`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.TIntfFlag) enum values:

```
TIntfFlag = (ifHasGuid, ifDispInterface, ifDispatch);
```

> ifHasGuid
>   Interface has a GUID (Globally Unique Identifier).
>
> ifDispInterface
>   Is a dispatch interface.
>
> ifDispatch
>   Can be dispatched.

A `Set` is a bitmask of values. Each enum value is represented by a specific bit in the mask. Within `TIntfFlagsBase`, `ifHasGuid` is bit 0, `ifDispInterface` is bit 1, and `ifDispatch` is bit 2.  So, a numeric value of 6 (`110b`) would be the `ifDispInterface` and `ifDispatch` flags enabled, but not the `ifHasGuid` flag. As such, the `IntfGuid` has no meaningful value, but still takes up space in the `TTypeData` for alignment purposes.

---

**Update**: I tested with XE2, and sure enough, I see `IntfFlags` is set to ordinal 64 (`TIntfFlag(6)`, like you see) instead of ordinal 6, as expected. The only difference between what I see and what you see is that I see the `Guid` is completely empty (all zeros).

---

**Update**: apparently, there are indeed additional flags present for interfaces that have method info enabled (the `{$M+}` directive), or that represent anonymous method types, which are not represented in the `TIntfFlag` enum.  I have filed a bug report for that:

[RSP-24631: System.TypInfo.TIntfFlag enum is missing flags](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24631)

In this case, `TIntfFlag(6)` is the flag for anonymous methods.

From [Undocumented "Interface flag" for IInvokable?](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/1167-undocumented-interface-flag-for-iinvokable/):

> It seems indeed as if the TIntfFlag enum was never extended since Delphi6 (I think that was when interface RTTI was introduced) - I can confirm that at least since XE an interface type with $M+ gets a fourth flag (lets call it ifHasMethodInfo) set.
>
> If the type is an anonymous method type ... then there is a 7th enum value in the set. The situations where bit 5 and 6 are set are unknown to me.
>
> ...
>
> I can confirm my findings with this code:
>
> ```pascal
> uses
>   SysUtils,
>   Rtti;
>
> type
>   TIntfFlagEx = (ifHasGuid, ifDispInterface, ifDispatch, ifMethodInfo, ifUnknown, ifUnknown2, ifAnonymousMethod);
>   TIntfFlagsEx = set of TIntfFlagEx;
>
>   {$M+}
>   IFoo = interface
>     ['{35CFB4E2-4A13-48E9-8026-C1558001F4B7}']
>     procedure Main;
>   end;
>   {$M-}
>
>   {$M+}
>   IBar = interface(TProc)
>     ['{AB2FEC1A-339F-4E58-B3DB-EC7B734F461B}']
>   end;
>   {$M-}
>
>   {$M+}
>   TMyProc = reference to procedure;
>   {$M-}
>
> procedure PrintIntf(typeInfo: Pointer);
> var
>   context: TRttiContext;
>   rttiInterface: TRttiInterfaceType;
>   flags: TIntfFlagsEx;
> begin
>   rttiInterface := context.GetType(typeInfo) as TRttiInterfaceType;
>   flags := TIntfFlagsEx(rttiInterface.IntfFlags);
>   Writeln(rttiInterface.Name, ' ', TValue.From(flags).ToString);
> end;
>
> begin
>   PrintIntf(TypeInfo(IInterface));
>   PrintIntf(TypeInfo(IInvokable));
>   PrintIntf(TypeInfo(IFoo));
>   PrintIntf(TypeInfo(TProc));
>   PrintIntf(TypeInfo(TFunc<Integer>));
>   PrintIntf(TypeInfo(TMyProc));
>   PrintIntf(TypeInfo(IBar));
>   Readln;
> end.
> ```
>
> prints this:
>
> ```
> IInterface [ifHasGuid]
> IInvokable [ifMethodInfo]
> IFoo [ifHasGuid,ifMethodInfo]
> TProc [ifAnonymousMethod]
> TFunc [ifAnonymousMethod]
> TMyProc [ifMethodInfo,ifAnonymousMethod]
> IBar [ifHasGuid,ifMethodInfo,ifAnonymousMethod]
> ```

Comment: The set has not value 6, it contains an element with value 6, it has value 64 (according to the inspector). So the value is not valid.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe for `TIntfFlagsBase` to have a numeric value of 64, `TIntfFlags` would need to have 7 elements, and that is simply not the case. I think you are misdiagnosing the issue. Also, you shouldn't be accessing `TI.TypeData` directly anyway, you should be passing `TI` to `GetTypeData()` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau `.TypeData` is the same as passing to `GetTypeData`, its a method on `TTypeInfo`. Also he is not misdiagnosing the issue. There seems to be some garbage data in the typeinfo for an anonymous method type (or some flags that are not documented).

Comment: Fortunately it is not a real issue. 
But I'm just curious about the why. 
Right now I think the data is unreliable for this type.

Comment: I have updated my answer. There are indeed several flags missing from the `TIntfFlag` definition. I have reported it to Embarcadero.