# Impossible to inspect (one) local string variable

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-10.3-rio

(*Based on comments I have edited the question to focus on the actual code part causing the issue, and added a section at the end*)

---

This is the local variables window in my Delphi 10.3.4 Win32 app, note that `lData` is missing:

[image]

The breakpoint corresponding to that screenshot is on the `if EmptyJSONArray(lData)` line at the end of the next code snippet:

```
function TLoketAPI.GetOneBatch(AJSONToXML: TJSONToXML; const ASelProps: TSelectionProps; var ABatchCount, AStatusCode: Integer): Boolean;
var
   lURL,
   lNextID,
   lData      : String;
   lLogHTTP   : TLogHTTP;
begin
   Result := false;
   if FAbort then Exit;
   lLogHTTP := TLogHTTP.Create(nil);
   Result := false;
   if ABatchCount = 0 then
      lNextID := ASelProps.GetNextIDValue
   else
      lNextID := ASelProps.GetSameIDValue;
   lURL := StringReplace(ASelProps.URL,'{id}',lNextID,[rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);
   if ABatchCount <> 0 then 
      if Pos('?',lURL) = 0 then lURL := lURL + '?pageNumber=' + IntToStr(ABatchCount+1)
                           else lURL := lURL + '&pageNumber=' + IntToStr(ABatchCount+1);
   try
      SetHTTPJSONProperties(lLogHTTP);
      try
         lLogHTTP.Get(lURL);
         if FAbort then
             Exit;

         lData := lLogHTTP.TransferredData;

         if FSaveJSON then
         begin
            lBatchCount := ABatchCount;  
            TThread.Synchronize(nil,
                                procedure
                                begin
                                   if lNextID = '' then 
                                      SaveToJSONFile(Format('%s batch (%d)',[ASelProps.TextID,lBatchCount]),lData)
                                   else
                                      SaveToJSONFile(Format('%s (%s) batch (%d)',[ASelProps.TextID,lNextID,lBatchCount]),lData);
                                end);
         end;
         if EmptyJSONArray(lData) then
```

`lData` contains valid data returned from the `logHTTP` call.

At the breakpoint (or anywhere else in the routine), `lData` does not show up in the local variables and cannot be inspected or watched.

The IDE gives:

> E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'lData'

This stuff is running in the main thread, optimization is off.

If I comment out the `TThread.Synchronize`, `lData` can again be inspected/watched.

What is going on here?

---

(*Added*)
In the comments, Remy and Dalija suggested that anonymous procedure as the reason, and linked this to the Embarcadero issue [RSP-22924 Watch shows undeclared identifier for captured local variables](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22924) (also reported under [RSP-21917](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21917)).

I still don't get it though: `RSP-22924` was edited to change its type to *Feature*. Feature? It looks like a bug to me.
And: (How) can this behavior be prevented? I'd really like to inspect `lData`.

Comment: @JanDoggen what does the *rest* of `GetOneBatch()` look like? Any chance that `lData` is being captured in an anonymous procedure in code you *haven't* shown yet?

Comment: I don't see that in your code (or I missed it... waiting for new glasses), but same thing happens if local variable is captured by anonymous method https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22924

Comment: The declaration of LogViaSynchronize might be helpful here.

Comment: @remy Indeed a `TThread.Synchronize`. I have edited the question because I still don't understand what's going on here.

Comment: @JanDoggen see [Variable Binding Mechanism](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi#Variable_Binding_Mechanism) and [How are anonymous methods implemented under the hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955052/). Since `lData` is being captured, it is not actually a local variable to `GetOneBatch()`, which is why you can't see it. It is actually a member of the implementation object behind the anonymous procedure. If you look closely, you will see that `lNextID` is also missing from the Watch window, too. Because it is also being captured.